# replace or remove characters that are not in regex with c++

Tags: c++, regex, whitelist

I would like to remove or replace any character that is not include in regexp with C++.
For example, if the expression is:[a-z] and the string is: "Hello-World", the return string will be: "Hello World", because only a-z are allowed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example program that does what you want using C++ regular expressions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const std::string text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    const std::regex vowels("[aeiou]");

    std::stringstream result;
    std::regex_replace(std::ostream_iterator<char>(result), text.begin(), text.end(), vowels, "");

    std::cout << result.str();  
}
```

The output is

> Th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg

It's pretty straightforward I think. This program removes every vowel, or rather, replaces every vowel with the empty string. You should be able to customize it to your needs easily. Comment if you have any further questions.

Edit: To turn the regex into a whitelist, just replace it with its inversion, `[^aeiou]`. Then the result will be

> euioouoeeao

because every character that is not a vowel has been replaced with the empty string.

Comment: Thank you !
What if i want to allow only the exact word: "Hello" and the word:"World" ? and remove everything else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string str = "The quiock brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    regex vowels("a|e|i|o|u");

    str = regex_replace(str, vowels, "");

    cout << str << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Never** use `bits/stdc++` nor `using namespace std`, and ditch any resource which says to use them.